# Calculation using Javascript - Math

Tags: javascript, jquery

JSON Statistics

```
cpu_usage:
percpu_usage:Array(4)
0:14808372153
1:518274597399
2:42110957200
3:133104944364
length:4
__proto__:Array(0)
total_usage:708298871116
usage_in_kernelmode:15350000000
usage_in_usermode:692790000000
__proto__:Object
online_cpus:4
system_cpu_usage:16883147380000000
```

I get a json like this that gives the cpu_usage

I made docker top and it's around 99-100% usage but my calculation give less than 1%. Something like `0,004`

What am I doing wrong?

```
success: function (statistics) {
    var totalUsage = statistics.cpu_stats.system_cpu_usage;
    var currentUsage =  statistics.cpu_stats.cpu_usage.total_usage;

    var cpuUsage = (currentUsage / totalUsage) * 100;
 }
```

The formula you need is this, but I don't have precpu_stats so I need to save the previous data somehow:

```
(cpu_stats.cpu_usage.total_usage - precpu_stats.cpu_usage.total_usage) / (cpu_stats.system_cpu_usage - precpu_stats.system_cpu_usage)
```

Comment: `precpu_stats.cpu_usage.total_usage` should be the cpu_usage of the array in sum?

Comment: `708298871116/16883147380000000` is clearly less than 1%, as you know (`0.00004`). There is nothing wrong with the math.

Comment: I don't have the precpu_stats. I need to save them. They are the previous data

Comment: @GerardoFurtado my calculation is wrong because I dont have precpu stats.

Comment: In that case you have a **completely** different question (which lacks information, by the way).